# Nonabelian and simple subnormal subgroups of a group.

Tags: finite-groups, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

Let $S \triangleleft \triangleleft$ $G$, where $S$ is nonabelian and simple. Show that $S^{G}$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

Notation: $S \triangleleft \triangleleft$ $G$ means $S$ is subnormal in  $G$, and $S^G$ is the set $\{g^{-1}Sg:g \in G\}$.

I am unable to approach this problem. How do I start?

Comment: Are you aware that $S^G$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ containing $S$?

Comment: Yes, since if $S \subseteq N \triangleleft G$, then $N$ contains all conjugates of $S$, and thus contains $S^G$ generated by these conjugates.

Comment: Ok, now consider a normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $S^G$. What can you say about the intersection with $S$?

Comment: It would be either $S$ or $(e)$, since their intersection is normal in $S$, but $S$ is simple. It can't be $S$, since that would mean there's a smaller normal subgroup than $S^G$ containing $S$, so it must be $(e)$.

Comment: Ok, let $N$ still be such a normal subgroup of $G$ and consider the subgroup $NS$. What can you say about the structure of this group?

Comment: Would $NS$ be subnormal in the group?

Comment: Hmm, I just realized I was missing a step here. I think this is the part where $S$ being subnormal will be needed.

Comment: I'm not able to proceed further. Could you post the complete solution as an answer?

Comment: As I said, I unfortunately realized that I am missing a step, so I don't actually have a full solution. Sorry about that.